# APK installation timeout error?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am using samsung galaxy S  application  shows these errors every time when i am staring android application.

I have restarted device but no response.

```
**[2013-07-02 13:21:40 - PauseFabLogin] Failed to install PauseFabLogin.apk on device '33323CF57AA400EC': timeout

[2013-07-02 13:21:40 - PauseFabLogin]
Launch canceled!**
```

Comment: Have you ever installed this app correctly? Did you get it from the Play Store, or are you using ADB?

Comment: no actually i am developing the application when i run this application then this error appear.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ADB timeout in Eclipse?

Comment: no ,i have to set time out for real device also ?

Comment: No, you set the installation timeout in Eclipse. Take a look at my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, try restarting your device.

If that doesn't work, in Eclipse go to:

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

Change it to something like 10000ms and try again.